# Any way to change default resolution in gspca driver for webcam?

Tags: webcam, skype

Who know how to change defaut resolution for my webcam:

I'm using a `4tech PK-52MF`. gspca is working fine with this webcam only on 320x240 resolution.

640x480 is very bad with it..

But skype uses 640x480.. And I can't change default resolution for skype. Ideas?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is no visible activity or information added to it for several months. I have flagged a moderator and am voting for it to be closed. If you feel that the question is not abandoned and that you still suffer from this issue please flag a moderator so that it can be re-opened.